# Jpg and webp images not showing on device but PNG are working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-image

I am using android studio 2.3.3 , Jpg and webp images are showning on android studio layout editor but not showing when installed app on phone instead it is shown as empty white screen. PNG images are working fine. Whats the reason for this?

My layout

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_categories"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Layout inside Editor ScreenShot

[image: [1]]

Screenshot of device

[image: [2]]

Note that PNG images are working but i want to use jpg or webp images as they consume less space.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Strange... This problem never happened to me before. Did you already try cleaning/rebuilding the project, and even restarted AS?

Comment: @DaveNOTDavid yes i tried still same